# Using BackgroundWorker instead of queuing

Tags: c#, wcf, message-queue

**Scenario**
I have a client that must call my web service synchronously, and I must respond within three seconds.  My web service calls another synchronously that usually takes about 12 seconds.

I'm considering using a BackgroundWorker over implementing queuing for simplicity and time constraints.  I have reason to believe this is a one-off scenario and the heaviest volume it might see will be about hundred a day.  So I don't think the usual concerns around the number of spun off processes is concerning.

The related threads I read speak to this as an option but generally not preferred.

**Question**
Is this a scenario--especially since I've not worked with MSMQ heavily nor in a great while--where a BackgroundWorker fits well?

Comment: don't bother the web service endpoint with this. it should really enqueue a background job that runs in its own process independently (unless you are on Core, where you could use `BackgroundService` as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1))

Comment: Using a background worker will be fine until your app crashes or the server goes down for maintenance. I'm not seeing how a queue is more complex than starting and managing background workers. *"one-off scenario"* don't believe the lie!

Comment: Fair enough.  Timeline isn't as tight as first imagined and agreed, queuing isn't a monster.  I've been bitten many times by relying on components that aren't built in (Oh, we didn't turn on MSMQ on UAT, too.  Did you actually want those consistent???).  @Dan Wilson, the lie is indeed a danger.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. When the request is made, add the params in a concurrent dictionary which are needed to make call the service which takes 12 seconds. Returns the response. Then in background you can use something like to do the work in background. Noneed to do different process etc.

```
public static class BackGroundWorker
{
    private static Thread WorkerThread = null;

    private static readonly object WorkerLock = new object();

    private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim ShutdownEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> backGroundExecutingRequestIds = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (WorkerThread != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (WorkerLock)
        {
            if (WorkerThread != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            ShutdownEvent.Reset();
            WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkerThreadProc));
            WorkerThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        if (WorkerThread == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ShutdownEvent.Set();
        WorkerThread.Join();
        WorkerThread = null;
    }

    private static void WorkerThreadProc() => WorkerThreadProcAsync().Wait();

    private static async Task WorkerThreadProcAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            while (!ShutdownEvent.Wait(0))
            {
                var ids = backGroundExecutingRequestIds.Take(25)?.Select(item => item.Key)?.ToList();
                while (ids?.Count > 0)
                {
                    //// Do the work of calling external Service which takes 12 seconds.
                    ids = Get the Next 25 Ids
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           ////LogException
        }
    }
}
```

}